# change legend title in ggbiplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend, ggbiplot

I'm having trouble manipulating `ggbiplot` such that I can specify what the title of the legend is. Using the package data:

```
library(ggbiplot)
data(wine)
wine.pca <- prcomp(wine, scale. = TRUE)
p <- ggbiplot(wine.pca, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, groups = wine.class, 
              ellipse =  TRUE, circle = TRUE)
```

I've tried the following

```
p + scale_fill_discrete(name="New Title")
p + guides(fill=guide_legend(title="New Legend Title"))
```

but I have no luck with either. I was wondering if somebody was familiar with this package and was able to advise as to how to change the legend title.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you are plotting points and their aesthetics is color and accordingly you should use `color=` instead of `fill=`

```
p+guides(color=guide_legend("Legend title"))
```

or

```
p + labs(color="Legend title")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime it works with `scale_color_discrete(name = 'Legend title')`.